# Excel - Filter unique values from Column A and move related values from Column B to other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel like this

```
Col1 - Col2
A - 1
B - 2
A - 3
B - 4
A - 5
```

I want to produce an excel from above one as shown below

```
Col1 - Col2 - Col3 - Col4
A - 1 - 3 - 5
B - 2 - 4
```

Is there a way in excel to do this?

Please help

Comment: There is with VBA. Do a loop through all your figures, and check with the `mod`operator whether its even or uneven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with formulas. It takes a small bit of formatting first though, so perhaps copy your data to a new sheet, then tweak.

First, get the unique values from Column A.  In your example, these would be `A` and `B`.  (For long lists, copy column A to some random column.  Select that column, go to Data--> Remove Duplicates. This will give you your unique list).

After you have the list, place it in Column D (for example).  Then, enter this formula as an array in column E (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6=$D1,ROW($A$1:$A$6)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS(INDIRECT("$A$1:A"&COLUMN()-4)))),"")
```

A couple notes: Adjust the range from rows 1 to 6 as necessary.  Also, if you choose a column other than column E to put this in, adjust the `Column()-4` part at the end so that the column number minus the other number (in my example, `4`) equals 1.  (In my formula the `Column()` returns 5 (for "E") and 5-4=1.

You can then drag over, and down, and it should work.

[image]