# Concatenate values based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a two column list of data in Excel. The first column being a question number from a test and the second column being a number referencing what is being tested on that question. Some elements are tested on more than one question.  What I want to be able to do is to list the question numbers that each element is tested on. For example:

```
   A            B      Should return:   C            D

1  Q            Ref                     Q            Ref
2  1            N1                      1,3,5        N1
3  2            N4                      2            N4
4  3            N1                      4            N3
5  4            N3
6  5            N1
```

I want this to be returned using a formula.

Problems I have are returning then concatenating an unspecified number of values from one column that reference to a particular criterion for another column that is further to the right.

EDIT: Looking for a formula answer, not VBA if possible

EDIT: Thanks all for your comments so far. I will have a look at each of the possible solutions given so far and let you know what I go with.  The 1,2,3 etc will need to be in the same cell.

Comment: In the "solution", do you have to have `1,3,5` in the same cell?

Comment: @pnuts - I ask that question because I think I have a formula that can do this, but he'll have to switch column D and C, and then drag the formula to the right.  If it works, my solution would require him to have `N1` in column C, then `1` would be in col. D, `3`, in E, and `5` in F.  That's why I am wondering if he needs those three in the same cell, or if it's okay to split them.

Comment: @Pnuts - well, I wouldn't be concatenating..it'd just be an array formula type thing. I'll see if it works and offer it up as an idea.

Comment: @BruceWayne - if you have a formula that can concatenate an unknown number of cell values please share it. If there is a static number of 6 possible strings to stitch together then yes, I certainly see your point; but an unknown (or even large) number of cells to concatenate presents obvious problems.

Comment: @pnuts - I agree, I think he's looking for non-VBA answer. I'm trying to get my formula working, but can't quite get it. It'd be based off of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050387/excel-filter-unique-values-from-column-a-and-move-related-values-from-column-b/34050659#34050659) I gave. So again, not really concatenating, but it *should* work if I can get the tweaks right.

Comment: Fair enough. I just don't think it can be done with any semblance of efficient calculation using native worksheet functions and that was a duplicate result with virtually duplicate sample data. See [Concatenate cell data into another data if values matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches).

Comment: As the data is obviously not sorted on column B, please disclose the actual number of rows in A:B.

Comment: @findwindow - Geez, how did you think Bruce Wayne made his billions and at least half of his own tech? Excel of course!

Comment: If you are willing to sort the data on column B, You could use a helper column with the following formula: `=IF(B2=B3,A2&","&C3,A2)` then you can use a vlookup on the unique ref to pull the first result of the helper column, which would be the total concatenated value.  Column C is the helper column in my example.

Comment: @pnuts - Every question about Excel has already been answered. We can offer newer technology answers (power query) but teh simple fact is that OPs asking rudimentary question have done NO research when simply googling the title of their question produces thousands of answers. I answered one today where I spent a couple of hours arriving at a resolution and the OP couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Jeeped `OPs asking rudimentary question have done NO research` THIS. I don't know why some members continue to humor them besides greed for points. I called out someone who had 32K points and still answered a troll. It's like giving money to the homeless. As long as a handful of people continue to do it, trolls will remain. Edit: lol Gary? [deleted my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210054/search-row-by-row-in-vba-with-two-criterias#comment56166289_34210054).

Comment: I can't chat remember Jeeped XD Edit: if you don't want to talk about it in public, that's fine. I probably won't go meta. Too political for my temperament. Anyways, <3 for having this discourse.

Answer (score 5):

Just to put my comment in an answer, so it make more sense.

First sort columns A and B on Column B.

In C2 put the formula:

```
=IF(B2=B3,A2&","&C3,A2)
```

Then copy down.

Then in Column E place your unique reference list.  And in D2 put:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$C$6,2,FALSE)
```

And copy down.

[image]

You can then hide column C.

It does require that it be sorted correctly and a helper column but it does stay to the formulas only rule.

Comment: @Pankajshrivastava this answer is old, and there is TEXTJOIN() with Office 365 that will do this without the middle step.

Answer (score 1):

By nature, Excel discourages this in worksheet formulas. I guess they figure that if you do this in a **User Defined Function** (aka *UDF*) and it hoops a workbook, it is your own fault and so be it. To that end, I've never seen a standard or array formula using only native worksheet functions that accomplishes this on a 'ragged-edge' array of cells and it's been tried a few times. Consider it `#REF!` by design.

You can run successive `IF` functions (up to 64 by xl2007+ standards) to accomplish the string stitching (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268386/loop-and-concatenate-in-excel-using-formula/34270082#34270082)) but you will also be limited to the total length of a formula (see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)). We also used 'helper' cells to run off the first 7 IFs in <=xl2003 then reference that cell in the first IF of another 7 nested IFs (rinse and repeat).

TLDR; In short, VBA is your most viable solution (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110321/concatenate-cell-data-into-another-data-if-values-matches)). Conditional string concatenation is fraught with problems by itself let alone in an array loop.

---

<sub>[CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d)</sub>