# Excel combine rows if column match

Tags: excel

I have more than 1000 rows of something like this:

```
a(column A) 1(column B)on first row,
a 2 second row,
a 4 thrid row,
b 6 fourth row,
b 5 fifth row,
c 8 sixth row,
c 3 seventh row,
```

I want this:  a(column A) 1,2,4(column B) on first row, b 6,5 on second row, c 8,3 on third row and so on.. I have more than 1000 rows of something like this. 
How do you do this?

Comment: Are your entries (a 1, a 2, a 4, etc) all in the same column? Or is it column A contains the letters and column B contains the numbers?  Also, what have you tried so far?  We can only help you if you show that you've tried to help yourself.  Generally speaking we don't do your work for you, simply help you correct your work or point you in the right direction.

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339316/concatenate-values-based-on-criteria/34341543#34341543).  It is almost identical.

Comment: It is unclear, what you expect as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty quickly with cell formulas:

[image]

With formulas shown:

[image]

Here we are first comparing A2 to A1, if they are the same, we concatenate, if they aren't the same then we just grab the B2 value.

Then in the next column we test for the length of the string that we just made. If the length of the string is larger than the string in the next row, then we grab the (a,b,c,d,e) value, otherwise we just drop a null in the column.

The last column (F) does the same thing, but grabs the concatenated value.

After you copy this down for all of your rows, you can just Copy>>Paste-Values column E and F and sort.

This could also be done with some VBA, but I think between the writing, debugging, and debugging, and debugging of the VBA subroutine, this formula method will be quicker and is more quickly adaptable (coming from a guy that writes a lot of VBA).